# Numeric keys not working in Bash Terminal (MacBook Pro)

Tags: bash, key, numeric

I'm trying to push a rails app to my remote Heroku repository from a MacBook Pro using the Bash Terminal.

The remote repository address contains numeric characters which are stripped out as soon as I copy/paste "git@heroku.com:app-name-[numbers].git".  If I try to type the numbers in manually, the comp just beeps.

Really stuck on this one!

Comment: Do the numeric keys work *before* you paste that string? If they do, what happens if you hand type the *whole* string?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a terminal setup problem.  First thing to try is simply to close down the terminal and restart; that'll be a fresh session.

If that doesn't work, carefully type the following

```
stty sane^J
```

or

```
^Jreset^J
```

to set it to something normal.

It sounds as if you're getting characters echoed at least, so that may be easy. The `^J` characters are LINEFEED, which is the actual ASCII character used for newline in UNIX-based systems.

Comment: Hi Charlie.

I've tried: 
stty sane [CTRL + J] and also
[CTRL + J]reset[CTRL + J] and still no luck :(.

Any other ideas?